# Is it possible to change the Full Text search stemming per language in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

A lot of things are customizable in SQL Server Full Text search:

- [Change the Thesaurus per language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-thesaurus-files-for-full-text-search)
- [Change the stoplist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search)
- [Install different word-breakers and filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/view-or-change-registered-filters-and-word-breakers)

But I can't find an option to change the stemming per language. The title in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search) suggests there is a way, but the article does not explain how. Is it possible?

I was wondering because [stemming does not seem to be working very well for every language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299202/full-text-search-stemming-not-returning-consistent-results-in-different-language).

Answer (score 1):

Stemming is configured per language via the registry.  Here is an example for changing it for English.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/change-the-word-breaker-used-for-us-english-and-uk-english

Comment: Looks interesting, unfortunately I don't have access to the registry on the production server so wouldn't work for my specific situation.

Comment: So the word breaker and stemmer are actually the same library. It should be possible to create a custom dll, but still would need access to the registry or file system.